# Entity Framework Core - Computed Column issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an entity class with a column called 'CalculatedId'. This column is obtained from an SQL statement and the column does NOT exist in the database table.

If I run app I get an error telling me that the column does not exist. This error is due to the framework trying to map the column to a physical column.

Below is my mapping code:

```
 modelBuilder
    .Entity<Widgets>()
    .Property(x => x.CalculatedId)
    .HasComputedColumnSql("select top 1 Id from MyTable");
```

I thought that this would tell EF not to look for a physical column as it's generated.

The only way I can get rid of the error is if I do this:

```
 modelBuilder
    .Entity<Widgets>()
    .Ignore(x => x.CalculatedId);
```

Problem there is that the column is totally ignored an not generated at all.

Can someone please connect the dots for me and clarify what needs to be done to make sure that the column is generated but EF does not look for it in the database.

**NB:** Has to be done in the fluent API, no data annotations.

Comment: Nothing can be done because what are you describing is not supported by EF (Core).

Comment: Is it supported by normal EF (EF 6) in any way?

Comment: @IvanStoev - What limitation causes EF not to support this?

Comment: EF6 has no such feature at all. EF Core `HasComputedColumnSql` is intended to create ..., well, the so called computed columns in the database *tables*, not to generate expression inside the SQL query. But you could post a request in their GitHub issue tracker :)

Comment: @IvanStoev - I did not understand what you meant. But with above API, ef creates table in database with provided SQL as computed column. Saving entities does not include the column in insert/update statements. Querying the table retrieves value of column correctly and assign to the property. So what is missing feature-wise? I tested above APIs and it works correctly. I couldn't use the same computed SQL as the database creation script EF generates is giving invalid syntax. I will follow up with that bug. Though in this case the issue seem to be something else.

Comment: @user281921 - Provide more info in your question. Simply stating "running app gives me error" is not enough. How did you create database? What are you trying to do when it crashes? What is the error you are getting? From database perspective, computed column may not exists physically always but it is always present logically and when it is referenced in a query, database computes value to put in that column.

Comment: @Smit I do understand what `HasComputedColumnSql` does. My comments were based on *what needs to be done to make sure that the column is generated but EF does not look for it in the database* part of the OP. The way I understand it, OP expects something like SQL `SELECT` query column expression (or logical equivalent of a database view). I have no idea why a real computed column in the database table does not work for them, although it sounds as viable solution to me. And as far as it's the only supported and working solution, I guess you might convince them using it :)

Comment: @Smit I did not say 'running app gives me an error' I said the error was that 'the column does not exist'. Maybe I'm however misunderstanding the purpose of HasComputedColumnSql. The CalculatedID is not an actual column in the database. It is simply an entity in the domain class which gets a value from an sql statement.

Comment: @user281921 - Therefore I asked for more information on the question. "Column does not exist" error can come from error in database creation or running a query.
The way you are worded above it seems that `HasComputedColumnSql` is not what you are looking for. You want to compute a value of domain only property (not mapped to database) using a SQL without any manual step. I am not sure what you are looking for exists in any ORM. Certainly not in EF Core. Ivan may be able to provider more insights if such functionality exists anywhere.

Comment: `HasComputedColumnSql` is to create a computed column in database. Many databases have concept of computed column, which is not stored physically but the column exists logically and its value computed using the underlying SQL when its queried. This API is EFCore's way of providing user to create & work with such column.

Comment: @IvanStoev If you add your first comment as answer I'll accept it.